# Charting a best value evolution plot using pyevolve and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyevolve

I'm trying to chart a plot of the best value evolution on a GA over time. I'm trying to use matplotlib to do it, and I'm using pyevolve for the GA.
My problem is that when I call the evolve function, it evolves the algorithm till the end and I have no way of getting the best value in each interation.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pyevolve already has a [plotting tool](http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/graphs.html), which uses the [data dumped](http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/graphs.html#usage) to a database using functionality built-in to pyevolve. Probably it fits your use case.

Otherwise, you could setup a [*step callback*](http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/intro.html#term-step-callback-function), in which you collect your own statistics for latter processing.

Comment: Thank you! I think this is exactly what I need!

Comment: do you happen to know the answer to this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33924153/how-to-use-step-callback-function-to-alter-all-the-fitness-values-of-current-gen